# Bitwise shift operator or ByteBuffer.wrap?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bytebuffer, endianness

Currently I am working on Big/Little Endian conversions and I am using bitwise operators. When I searched on the web, many have implemented with `ByteBuffer.wrap()`. I have never used `ByteBuffer` before, how efficient is it when compared to bitwise operators? Which is better performance wise?

Comment: It is fast enough that it should not make a difference; have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way to convert a specific, say, `int` between big and little endian is `Integer.reverseBytes`.

Comment: I am trying to convert long data.

Comment: Then use `Long.reverseBytes`.